# How to run HelloWorld program in spring and maven without using Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have just now started learning spring and I am trying to execute sample HelloWorld program using maven but without eclipse.

> My Build using maven succeeds but I can not run the project.

Can Anybody help me?

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloWorld {
   private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }

   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
   }
}
```

**MainApp.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

      obj.getMessage();
   }
}
```

**Beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld">
       <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org 2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tutorialspoint</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloSpring</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>HelloSpring</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run this project?

Comment: cd target\                                                          java -cp HelloSpring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld

Comment: Your class is `MainApp`, not `HelloWorld`

Comment: But no MainApp class is generated

Comment: @Govan: ??? There is a MainApp in your example?!

Comment: @GyroGearless I can't get you/

Comment: @Govan - i can't get you; there is a MainApp.java in your question, how can you say it does not exist?

Comment: yeah there is MainApp.java but its class file is not generated when running maven

Comment: So then your initial assumption "My Build using maven succeeds" is just wrong! If your `MainApp.java` does not get compiled, there must be something wrong with your project setup.

Comment: Can you turn your HelloSpring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar into a zip file and see if your MainApp is there ?!

Comment: As far as I know, you can change in the pom.xml, packaging to WAR, give command mvn install(don't ask me where as you don't have an IDE), then copy the war file and deploy it in apache tomcat to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify an entry point in pom configuration.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.path_to_main_class</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Tutorial is here
[How to create a jar file with Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/)

Comment: After adding this I get the following:                        Malformed POM /home/elangovan/Documents/HelloSpring/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'plugin' (position: START_TAG seen ...<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>\n  <plugin>... @10:11)  @ /home/elangovan/Documents/HelloSpring/pom.xml, line 10, column 11 -> [Help 2]

Comment: Put `<plugin>` in `<plugins>` section

Comment: @MariuszS I have missed build tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Program with Spring can be started like other java program.

```
java -cp <your classpath>  com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld
```

Usually the class path contains many libraries:  Spring, hibernate, jdbc driver and many others.
For avoiding long classpath I use jar with dependencies.
In this case your command line extremely simple:

```
java -jar MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myappid</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Your dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.tutorialspoint.MainApp</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>junit:junit</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>junit/framework/**</include>
                                        <include>org/junit/**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>org/junit/experimental/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org/junit/runners/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.PluginXmlResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```